# Q4M MySql message queue compilation fails with dozen of errors

Tags: mysql, compilation

I'm trying to compile Q4M (http://q4m.31tools.com) for MySql 5.1.44 since there is not a precompiled package available for this release.

The installation instructions seem straightforward (http://q4m.31tools.com/install.php) but I did have to put the files in others dirs than mentioned - maybe because I'm using Ubuntu.

Here's what I did so far:

1) Downloaded MySql 5.1.44 source from http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-5.1.44.tar.gz/from/http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/mysql/ and unpacked it to "/home/elu/Desktop/mysql-5.1.44"

2) Download Q4M source from http://q4m.31tools.com/dist/q4m-0.9.tar.gz and unpacked it to "/home/elu/Desktop/q4m-0.9"

3) I got into the Q4M dir and did:

`$ ./configure
...

checking for mysql source code... configure: error: "no mysql source provided"`

4) I figured I needed to supply --with-mysql argument as indicated by the argumentation so I did:

`$ ./configure
...

checking for mysql source code... "/home/elu/Desktop/mysql-5.1.44"

failed to lacate mysql 5.1 installation

Please specify mysql 5.1 directory with --prefix option.`

Now I'm stuck. The manual says that providing MySql installation directory is optional so why does it ask me to provide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install libmysqld-dev. It should do the trick.